# split string into an array not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string like so 1500, 1500 and I am trying to split it into array like so:

```
string[] PretaxArray = Pretax.Split(", ");
```

but I get this error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you want to split on comma with space `", "`, or only on the occurrence of comma ? , you can use `string[] PretaxArray = Pretax.Split(',');`  and then trim leading and trailing space from each item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this:

```
string[] PretaxArray = Pretax.Split(',');
```

In the `Split` method we *usually* pass a character or an array of characters and not a string.

Actually, in order to be more precise, you could pass an array of strings. But this is not your case - I assume that from the code you have posted.

You could take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), where all the overloaded versions of `Split` method are aggregated.

Comment: Not really clear from the quesiton, but the OP could be looking to split on string `", "` *(comma and space)*

Comment: @Habib you are correct. Thank you for your comment. For this reason I included a link to the MSDN, where we can find all the overloads of the `Split` method.

Answer (score 6):

[String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.100).aspx) has another overload

```
string Pretax = "1500, 1500";
string[] PretaxArray = Pretax.Split(new[] {", "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```